# Как добавить к символу цифру изменив цифровой код символа ASCII

Tags: java

Добрый день не могу разобраться как изменить символ

допусти у нас есть символ `'K'` в  ASCII этот символ 75(вроде)

мне нужно что к примеру к коду символа `'K'` прибавить число 5 получиться 80 это уже буква `'P'`

```
 char chark = 'k';
 char charp = chark + 5; //это первое что пришло в мою дырявую голову(
как мне решить это?
```

Заранее спасибо огромное!

Comment: (char)((byte)chark +5)???

Comment: сработало спасибо, а обязательно переводить в байт  char chark ='K';
        char charP = (char)(chark +5);
        System.out.println(charP); тоже работает @AzizUmarov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `byte` нельзя - у него недостаточный диапазон для общей работы с `char`.

При сложении `char` и `int` результат получается `int`, поэтому его нужно вернуть обратно к `char`.

```
char chark = 'k';
char charp = (char)(chark + 5);
```

Такой вариант правильный.